# How do i install wine in Ubuntu 14.04 lts?

Tags: package-management, wine, dependencies

I have been trying to install wine but when i use the command `sudo apt-get install wine` i get this message:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
  wine : Depends: wine1.6 or wine1.8 but it is not going to be installed
  E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

if you want extra info tell me the commands and i will post them

Comment: Try following instructions on their website https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Comment: i have tried but got this at the last step.       

'Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-devel : Depends: wine-devel
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.'

Comment: What happens if you install wine-devel?

Comment: just as i said i get the error mentioned above 



   {Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation: The following packages have unmet dependencies: winehq-devel : Depends: wine-devel E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.}

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

It should fix the dependencies and automatically install missing packages.

If it is not enough or you get some errors, you can try to install missing packages manually with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7 unity-control-center
```

---

For more information about `apt-get` and `-f` option you can read manual running this:

```
man apt-get
```

I hope this could help you.

Comment: when i used the second command you gave me i got this            "libcheese-gtk23 is already the newest version.
libcheese7 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded."     so obviously trying to instal wine gave me the same error as before

Comment: @Alux Anastasakos try also to install `unity-control-center`.

Comment: i already had that installed so no change